# New project with GULP

Tags: npm, gulp, workflow

I made a project using GULP and I downloaded several modules with the NPM cmd. For a new project, should I copy/paste my old project with the files "gulpfile.js", "package.json" and the folder "node_module" or i have to redownload all the modules ? I tried to copy/paste and it worked perfectly, but maybe there is an another way to do it (like download each module with one command line) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying your old **package.json** file into your new project is perfectly reasonable when you also use a copy of your existing **gulpfile**.

Now, instead of copying your **node_module** folder just run **npm install**. It does exactly the same thing as copying and pasting but with the added bonus of checking package versions, deprecated dependencies, and so on...

Quick tip: If you ever run into problems as I have deleting/removing packages given that theirs paths might be longer than what the OS allows use the tool **rimraf**. Install it globally and then you can call **rimraf** on anything. *CAUTION! this tool will erase everything no questions asked*